# JAVA PROGRAMMING - unDUPLICATOR error on logic

Tags: java

I was doing this "Random number game" and have come up with the following code...

```
public void generate()
{
    for(int i=0; arr[i]!=arr[i+1]; i++)
    {
        for(int l=0; l<10; l++)
        {
            Random rdm=new Random();
            arr[l] = rdm.nextInt(range)+1;

        }
        lbtest.setText("Random Numbers: "+arr[0]+"-"+arr[1]+"-"+arr[2]+"-"+arr[3]+"-"+arr[4]+"-"+arr[5]+"-"+arr[6]+"-"+arr[7]+"-"+arr[8]+"-"+arr[9]);
        bgen.setEnabled(false);
        gametext.setText("");
    }


}
```

I made 3 different levels for this random number game which means the range of random numbers(1-20, 1-30, and 1-50). the 1-30 and 1-50 levels work. but when I click on 1-20, the code doesn't generate any numbers.

I tried debugging the program to see where this code has the error but JCreator doesn't help. It doesn't display the line with the error.

Comment: jcreator in 2012? not related, but change your ide, use eclipse.

Comment: @AmitBhargava_the random numbers are stored in arr[i]

Comment: @deporter_i've thought of that already... but i cant. my prof won't agree on that.

Comment: @Bohemian_thank you sir. and sorry i forgot to use tags the right way. XD i haven't yet got the hang of things here at stackoverflow.

Comment: The intent of this code is very unclear, for example: iterating over an array with an unsafe exit condition; an inner loop working with a completely unrelated loop index (which can only set array entries 0 - 9)

Answer (score 0):

First off, Declare your random variable outside your loops, or else your numbers won't be random at all.

Secondly, the `for(int i=0; arr[i]!=arr[i+1]; i++)` loop looks very bizarre.  if the first 2 members of `arr` are the same, then the rest of the code you posted won't execute at all.  Also, if the last 2 members of `arr` are not the same, then your code will throw an exception.

The the condition `arr[i]!=arr[i+1];` has the potential to produce the bug you describe.

If you elaborate a little bit on your requirements, I might be able to help you further.